# Bug na validação do Javascript

Tags: javascript

Olá. Eu desenvolvi uma barra de processos com um botão de next e preview, onde clicando em next a barra vai reduzindo os processos.

Eu tenho 2 campos na tela, "position" e "totalItems", onde position precisa ser menor ou igual a totalItems.

Meu problema é que a minha barra tem 3 sessões e um total de itens, quando a primeira seção termina o contador entende que a barra acabou e não continua a contar as posições, informando que o documento está no primeiro registro.

Assim...

A primeira sessão tem 9 itens, então o botão vai de 0 a 8, onde 8 > 78 = false.
Mas a próxima posição, que seria 9 a comparação 9 > 78 = true e apresenta o alerta.

Colocando um console.log eu vejo que o resultado dos campos estão corretos, um com valor 8 e outro com o valor 78, que é o total de itens.

```
bindEvent("click",".next",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var indicator           = $("input[name='indicator']").val(),
        position            = $("input[name='position']").val(),
        totalItens          = "<cfoutput>#arrayLen(session.Propostas)#</cfoutput>"; //Pega o total de itens em uma sessão do CF = 78
    if(position >= totalItens){
        alert("Você está no último registro");
    }
    else{
        //increment +1
        position++;
        $("input[name='position']").val(position);
        //Tira 1 do total de itens
        $("input[name='indicator']").val(("<cfoutput>#arrayLen(session.Propostas)#</cfoutput>")-position);
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Bom eu acabei identificando o problema, por algum motivo o js está tratando o conteúdo das minhas variáveis como string.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, acabei identificando o meu problema.

O js está tratando o conteúdo dos campos como strings, então eu usei o Number do js e funcionou.

Ficou assim...

```
bindEvent("click",".next",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var indicator           = $("input[name='indicator']").val(),
        position            = $("input[name='position']").val(),
        totalItens          = "<cfoutput>#arrayLen(session.Propostas)#</cfoutput>"; //Pega o total de itens em uma sessão do CF = 78
    if(Number(position) >= Number(totalItens)){
        alert("Você está no último registro");
    }
    else{
        //increment +1
        position++;
        $("input[name='position']").val(position);
        //Tira 1 do total de itens
        $("input[name='indicator']").val(("<cfoutput>#arrayLen(session.Propostas)#</cfoutput>")-position);
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```